# Are all constexpr variable implicitly inline?

Tags: c++, c++17, linkage, inline-variable

I was playing around with *auto template parameters* and I was surprised that this code didn't compiled:

```
constexpr auto bar = 2;

template<auto& T>
struct Foo {
    auto operator()() const { return T; }
};

int main() {
    Foo<bar> b;
    b();
}
```

Visual Studio 15.7 (preview 4) spit out these errors:

> ```
> error C2970: 'Foo': template parameter 'T': 'bar': an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument
>  note: see declaration of 'Foo'
>  note: see declaration of 'bar'
> error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'
>  note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<0>' being compiled
> error C2973: 'Foo': invalid template argument 'int'
>  note: see declaration of 'Foo'
> ```

Then, after adding `inline`, the error got away!

```
constexpr inline auto bar = 2;
```

I thought `constexpr` variables were implicitly `inline`. Also, how does that affect the linkage of my variable `bar`?

Comment: @miradulo yeah of course... But GCC and Clang now also allows for reference or pointer to object of any linkage as a non-type template parameter. So either constexpr variable really should be inline and this is a visual studio bug, or GCC and Clang accept the variable but all have internal linkage.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: for implicitly defined copy/move constructor, it is constexpr and inline. but not for primitive types.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Are all constexpr variable implicitly inline?

No. Only constexpr functions and constexpr static data members are implicitly inline ([[dcl.constexpr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-3)).

> Also, how does that affect the linkage of my variable bar?

A constexpr variable is `const` ([[dcl.constexpr]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#9.sentence-1)). A non-inline `const` variable that is not explicitly declared `extern` has internal linkage ([[basic.link]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3)).

Comment: Ah! This is where I got confused, the implicit inline is only for static data members constexpr, not all constexpr variables.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot you have the right to be confused, the original standard paper itself is wrong in that it does not mention that distinction. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf