# constexpr variable in source file global scope

Tags: c++, constexpr

What is the proper way to declare a constexpr constant in a source file? I'm split between two ways:

```cpp
constexpr int ORDER = 1;
```

vs

```cpp
namespace {
constexpr int ORDER = 1;
} // unnamed namespace
```

The reason I question the usefulness of wrapping into an unnamed namespace is because at global scope, `constexpr` implies `static`. So similar to how in header files writing

```cpp
static constexpr int ORDER = 1;
```

makes `static` just a repetition, I'm assuming that the same should apply in source files as well, hence internal linkage should be guaranteed for "`constexpr` variables declared in a source file's global scope".

Is this the case? Are there different suggestions?

Comment: Namespaces are preferable in C++. Static specifies the lifetime of the variable. A static constexpr variable has to be set at compilation, because its lifetime is the the whole program. Without the static keyword, the compiler isn't bound to set the value at compilation, and could decide to set it later. PS: I would wrap such constants in a structure.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson: `constexpr` definitely requires compile-time initialization (although as-if can as usual do a lot).

Comment: In a header you should [use `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53794625/8586227) and never an unnamed namespace or `static`.

Comment: @DavisHerring I added a bounty to draw more attention to the question. Do you agree with the existing answer? Do you want to contribute a different answer?

Comment: @LorahAttkins: The answer here is fine: I just commented about the header case because it matters more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not required to enclose `constexpr` variables, declared in a source file, in an unnamed namespace. Since the end goal is to achieve internal linkage you have to remember [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3):

> The **name of an entity that belongs to a namespace scope has internal
> linkage** if it is the name of
>
> - a variable, variable template, function, or function template that is explicitly declared static; or
> - a non-template variable of non-volatile **const-qualified type**, unless
>
>   - it is explicitly declared extern, or
>   - it is inline or exported, or
>   - it was previously declared and the prior declaration did not have internal linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

i.e since ["`constexpr` implies `const` and `const` on namespace scope implies internal linkage"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489130/4224575), it's superfluous to say

```
static constexpr int ORDER = 1;
```

or

```
namespace {
  static constexpr int ORDER = 1;
}
```

If you want a tangible proof of the internal linkage property, consider [this compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49913011/4224575)

Comment: That being said, it doesn't hurt to put your singly defined internally linked variables inside a named namespace to improve structuring your code.